# Using Ranges from command line

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a task which is ,I need to display to the user the mathematical tables the user wants . However the input must be using command line arguments . I know how to do this with single input .. however I have to add a functionality so that when the user types : my program 5-7 i have to display the multiplicative tables of 5 ,6 and 7 ..how can I work around with this ?

This must be done in C++

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
int i;
locale loc;
int tables[argc-1];

if(argc <=1){
 cout<<"NO ARGUMENTS PASSED"<<endl;
 exit(0);
}

for(i=1;i<=argc;i++){
if( isdigit(argv[i],loc)){
tables[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
}

for (i=1; i<=argc;i++){
 cout<<argv[i]<<endl;
}


}
```

Comment: `argc` and `argv`?

Comment: Can the arguments be e.g. `5 - 7` with spaces in between? Or does it have to be `5-7` without spaces. Either way it's all there in your `argv` array for you to read and parse.

Comment: yes but when the user enters 5-7 ? how can I split the input?

Comment: There are ways to split [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) into [sub-strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), if you can [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the position of the dash.

Comment: it doesn't matter, `argv[1]` would point to string like `5-7`, all you need is to parse that string into two numbers, min and max, and you got the range

Comment: Command-line arguments are separated by spaces. A space character will split an argument. Arguments that may contain spaces (eg filenames) should be enclosed in double quotation marks (eg "Your String").

Comment: I have uploaded the code in the edit .. i do not know why there's an exception happening

Answer (score 1):

First decide whether to handle "tables 2-3", "tables 2 - 3" or both.

Lets say we opt for both. So argc must be either 2 for the one argument case (remember argv[0] is the program name) or 4 for the three argument case. if it's not 2 or 4, print out a usage message to tell the user how to use the program and quit.

If is is 4, argv[1] must be an integer, argv[2] must be the string "-", and argv[3] must be an integer. You might also require that argv[3] be greater than argv[1].
So test these. strcmp will test for the middle. The function strtol() provides an easy way to test for a valid integer (the end pointer should point to the nul on exit if it is an integer).

If argc is 2, the string must be in the forma 12-30, an integer,a hyphen and an integer. There are several ways of testing for this. One is to call strtol, then check that the end pointer points to hyphen, then call strtol again on the character after the hyphen. You could also use the function sscanf().

Now decide how to handle cases such as negative or zero, and huge values maybe beyond your machine precision.

Finally print out the tables.